Cox Proportionall Hazards compared to AFT and the proportional hazards assumption
I am dealing with survival analysis in R in big population datasets with millions of rows. My first option was a cox regression
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ 
                        var1+ var2+ var3 , data = data)

however based on Schoenfeld residuals the proportional hazards assumption was violated for some covariates and globbaly. I tried time transformation but considering the size of the data the model cannot be handled computational (error message about vector allocation of 70-80Gb).
As an alternative I tried fitting an AFT.
model_wei <- survreg(Surv(time, event)~ 
                       var1+ var2+ var3 , data = data, dist = "weib", maxiter=100)

After creating models with exp, wei, logn and logl, the best fit was provided from the logn model (based on AIC).
Can you please help me understand the difference in interpretation between the Hazard Ratio in Cox regression and the exp(coef) from an AFT?
My procedure for selecting the best distribution for the AFT was comparing AIC and then plotting the residuals to check normality as:
resid <- log(data$time) -  model.lognormal$linear.predictors 
qqnorm(resid)
qqline(resid)

The resulting plot is

When accounting for the censoring:
library(rms)
f <- psm(Surv(time, event) ~ var1 + var2+ var3+ ... + var20,
         dist='lognormal', y=TRUE, data=data)
r <- resid(f)
with(data, {
  survplot(r,  label.curve=FALSE)

} )

Source
I get:

Can this be considered adequate?
What are my options if it is not?
And final question, is it relevant in any case to present a cox regression model even if the proportional hazards assumption is violated, if the hazard does not seem too change dramatically over time and the direction always remain the same?

The example given by Dimitris was for a Weibull model, where a standard extreme value distribution is the proper comparison for the residuals. As you are fitting a log-normal model, you need to display the survival function for a standard normal distribution instead. If you're having trouble with implementation, try the psm() function for fitting AFT models in Frank Harrell's rms package and use its survplot() function on the residuals to get what you want. See RMS, Sec. 19.2.

Thank you for this correction. I have tried to implement the code from the rms package, and I have updated my question accordingly.

That looks pretty good. You might consider repeating the modeling and residual evaluation on other AFT distribution families (Weibull fit residuals against extreme value, log-logistic fit residuals against logistic, etc.) for comparison.

First, note that the Weibull distribution (and its special case, the exponential distribution) admits an AFT and PH parameterization. This means that the AFT models with the Weibull and exponential distribution also assume proportional hazards.
To select an appropriate distribution for the error terms in an AFT model, you need to account for the fact that the residuals from such a model are censored. Hence, the QQ-plot will not be appropriate in this case. For an alternative procedure that accounts for censoring, see here.

Thank you very much. I have edited my question by adding the resulting plot of the KM estimator of the residuals.
